# i cant call phone number flutter correctly

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello i try to build button call phone number when click .but when click appear different number this is "94343832826624531" and this is not my number in database

```
   FlatButton(
          onPressed: () => launch("tel:widget.data.mobile1"),
          child: new Text("Call me")),
    ),
```

Comment: Did you try: 
launch("tel:"+widget.data.mobile1),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to use either

```
 FlatButton(
      onPressed: () => launch("tel:${widget.data.mobile1}"),
      child: new Text("Call me")),
),
```

Or

```
 FlatButton(
      onPressed: () => launch("tel:"+widget.data.mobile1),
      child: new Text("Call me")),
),
```